# htmlagilitypack getting field-item

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have HTML that needs to be processed using htmlagilitypack in C#. Problem is I am not able to print it properly.
example 1:

```
<tr class="even">
  <td class="left">Names:</td><div class="field field-name-field-services field-type-reference field-label-hidden">
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">Abby</div>
<div class="field-item odd">Mary/Joe
</div><div class="field-item even">Cindy</div
><div class="field-item odd">Sally</div><div class="field-ite
m even">Zoey</div><div class="field-item odd">Donna</div><div class="field-item even">Kristie</div>
<div class="field-item odd">Mary</div><div
class="field-item even">Libby &amp; Monroe</div><div class="field-item odd
">Nancy/Smith</div></div></div></td></tr>
```

I want the output to be 
Abby Mary/Joe Cindy Sally Donna Mary Libby & Monroe Nancy/Smith.

Example 2:

```
    <tr class="even">
  <td class="left">Names:</td><div class="field field-name-field-services field-type-reference field-label-hidden">
<div class="field-items">
<div class="field-item even">Cindy</div>
<div class="field-item odd">Sally</div><div class="field-item even">
Linda</div></div></div></div></td></tr>
```

Output is Cindy Sally Linda

This is what I tried.

```
HtmlDocument hdoc2 = new HtmlDocument();
hdoc2.LoadHtml(test);
var innernode1 = hdoc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr//td");
Console.Writeline(innernode1[0].innertext);
```

I am getting an object instance not set to an instance of an object error. Shouldn't it print the first name?

Comment: No your code doesn't get `object instance not set to an instance of an object`. It is not even compilable (I tested it after fixing the compilation errors, and returned `Names:`).  **Post a real code**

Comment: This is real code from my program

Comment: a) it is `WriteLine` not `Writeline` b) it is `InnerText` not `innertext`.  How can it be real code? How can you get this runtime exception with a non-compilable code? Respect the readers and take your time to ask a correct question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
hdoc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//items/div[starts-with(@class, 'item')]/text()");
```

That should select all the text nodes you want.